# AndroidX YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi getting errors

Tags: android, android-fragments, androidx

After migrating to `AndroidX` `YoutubeAndroidPlayerAPi` getting errors inside the `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` 
showing

> required androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

Answer (score 0):

As you migrate you project to `androidx`. So you need to verify that all the imports of used libraries are mounted to `androidx`.

If you go to `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment' class and check the import class of`Fragment`.

Just remove that import and import the fragment with **androidx.fragment.app.Fragment**

It will resolve your issue. It may cause same on other files as well, repeat the same steps.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your import

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

replace with

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
```